# Unable to resolve property: Id

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm getting the following error message:

```
NHibernate.HibernateException: NHibernate.HibernateException: Unable to resolve property: Id.
```

This error is thrown from the following line of code:

```
User userFound = session.QueryOver<User>()
                   .Where(x => x.Id == testObjects.TestUser.Id)
                   .SingleOrDefault();
```

My abbreviated mappings are as follows:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Table("USER_HEADER");
        Id(x => x.Id, "USER_ID")
            .GeneratedBy.Foreign("UserLocation");

        HasOne(x => x.UserLocation)
            .PropertyRef(x => x.Id)
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class LocationMap : ClassMap<Location>
{
    public LocationMap()
    {
        Table("LOC_HEADER");
        Id(x => x.Id, "LOC_ID");

        HasOne(x => x.User)
            .PropertyRef(x => x.Id);
    }
}
```

I was able to query a User object before I added this relationship to `Location` so I know it has something to do with it but I'm not sure what exactly.  I can successfully create a `User` object that is tied to a `Location` but cannot query it.  Using `ISession.Get` produces the same error as the above QueryOver statement.

Below is the overall unit test I am running that is failing:

```
    public void Can_Create_User()
    {
        using (NHibernate.ISession session = SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession())
        {
            using (NHibernate.ITransaction tran = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                session.Save(testObjects.TestValidationDetail);
                session.Save(testObjects.TestUser);
                tran.Commit();
            }
        }

        using (NHibernate.ISession session = SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession())
        {
            User userFound = session.QueryOver<User>().Where(x => x.Id == testObjects.TestUser.Id).SingleOrDefault();

            Assert.IsNotNull(userFound);
            Assert.AreEqual(userFound.Id, userFound.UserLocation.Id);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out this was caused by me incorrectly using `PropertyRef`.  In my instance I did not need to use this. The error was being generated because there was no property named `Id` but there was an ID named `Id`. I corrected my issues by changing my mappings to:

```
HasOne(x => x.UserLocation)
        .PropertyRef(x => x.Id)
        .Cascade.All();
```

**to**

```
HasOne(x => x.UserLocation)
        .Cascade.All();
```

and

```
HasOne(x => x.User)
        .PropertyRef(x => x.Id);
```

**to**

```
HasOne(x => x.User)
```

Comment: in my case I was assuming the remote reference is not the primary key - basically the same. Thanks for posting!

Comment: Yes it worked for me too, I used the Nhibernate Map Generator, and it has generated the mapping as a property references, when it wasn´t needed because the Property is actually the ID.

Answer (score 2):

`PropertyRef` maps to `property-ref` is a legacy feature, it is meant to allow you to create many-to-one associations when the association is not done on the primary key of the association.

I am guessing you want to specify on what property the join is to be made and that is why you used PropertyRef.. if you are using Nhibernates default convention in the mapping for the Id of UserLocation you dont need to explicitly specify the property.. if you are explicitly giving the column name then you need to do the same here, but in that case you need to specify the exact same column name.

Hope that helps..

Comment: I answered my own question below shortly after running into this problem.  I thought I needed property ref because the primary keys between the tables were different names (loc_id and user_id) but really the same id.  This is not the intended use for the `property-ref` feature as I learned.

Comment: I did not see your answer to the question.. was using the IPAD app